# dynamically added checkbox handler for Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, checkbox

I have some elements that get added to my html page in response to a user's interaction with jQuery:

```
 addFields = '<div class="individual">
    <div class="member"> 
    Name:&nbsp;<input class="firstName" type="text">
    <input class="lastName" type="text">
    <input class="cit" onChange="citizenInfo(this)" type="checkbox">Non U.S. Citizen?<br/>
    </div> 
    <div class="citInfo" style="display:none"> 
    Country<input class="countryBirth" type="text"> 
    </div>
    </div>';
$('#items').append(addFields);
```

Now I want the 'cit' checkbox to toggle the visibility of the 'citInfo' div.  So in my handler for the checkbox I have this:

```
function citizenInfo(obj) {
     $(obj).parent().parent().find('.citInfo').toggle();
}
```

This works in Safari and Firefox but now in IE.  How can I get IE to toggle the visibility of this div in response to the checkbox being clicked?

Answer (score 1):

You should bind a click event to the checkbox, check the value of the checkbox and act accordingly.

```
$( 'input.cit' ).click( function () {

    var div = $( '.citinfo' );

    $(this).attr( 'checked' ) ? div.show() : div.hide();

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I just tried this and it doesn't work even in Safari.  Please note that these items are being added dynamically, not on the page load.

Comment: then $( 'input.cit' ).live( 'click', function () { // code here } ...this way every time you add a new checkbox, with the live method it gets that event handler.

Comment: Well, I actually figured it out.  I just changed 'onChange' to 'onClick' in my checkbox declaration and voila!

Comment: Great! Just a hint, since you are using jQuery which provides the live() method, I think it would be better to rely on that, instead of having dirty html. Anyway good job! :)